# How to get cursor to go to a specific column in a datagrid?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

How do I get the cursor to go to a specific column on a data grid in Vb.net? It can be any row on the grid.

Comment: `DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1([The Column Name or Index], DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)`

Comment: I tried googling it but got a lot of other unnecessary and complicated code.  I just needed something simple.

Comment: Firstly, are you really talking about a `DataGrid` or is it a `DataGridView`? If the former, is this a WinForms project or something else? There are lots of controls with similar or identical names that are only used in certain project types and it is a waste of everyone's time for us to try to guess which one you mean. ALWAYS provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.